# Error during a git clone on a private repository (Centos)

Tags: git

I'm using Centos and I have a weird error when I try to clone my private repository from Github.com

I just do

```
git clone https://github.com/Clemzd/GCLChallenge.git
```

And I get this error :

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/makeitgreen/Documents/GCLChallenge/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing     
https://github.com/Clemzd/GCLChallenge.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

It sounds like I didn't configure my git well. I remember that I did that to save my password and the error probably comes from this but I don't know how to cancel this.

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

I tried on an another machine and it works well because it ask me my credentials.

Thank you for your help!

SOLUTION : my centos had a git version < 1.7.9 and I had to specify the credentials as part of the url so I've improved the version to 2.2.0 and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you specifying wincred even being on Centos? 
 You can try unsetting them with `git config --global --unset credential.helper`

Then read http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials or [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I also tried to remove ~/.gitconfig but I still have the error

Comment: if your centos has a git version < 1.7.9 you have to specify the credentials as part of the url I suppose or use the netrc method, is that your case?

Comment: that is probably place for another question, accept this answer if you think resolved the git issue, and ask another one with the jenkins error, stackoverflow is not really suited for multiple questions on the same "page". (hint, maybe there is only a permission or space problem, not really sure though)

Comment: Ok thanks! How I can do to accept you answer in comment?